# Sorting algorithm proof and running-time

Tags: algorithm, performance, sorting, big-o, master-theorem

*Hydrosort* is a sorting algorithm. Below is the pseudocode.

```
*/A is arrary to sort, i = start index, j = end index */

    Hydrosort(A, i, j):                 // Let T(n) be the time to find where n = j-1+1

      n = j – i + 1                              O(1)
      if (n < 10) {                              O(1)
        sort A[i…j] by insertion-sort            O(n^2) //insertion sort = O(n^2) worst-case
        return                                   O(1)
      }
      m1 = i + 3 * n / 4                         O(1)
      m2 = i + n / 4                             O(1)
      Hydrosort(A, i, m1)                        T(n/2)
      Hydrosort(A, m2, j)                        T(n/2)
      Hydrosort(A, i, m1)                        T(n/2)
```

T(n) = O(n^2) + 3T(n/2), so T(n) is O(n^2).  I used the 3rd case of the Master Theorem to solve this recurrence.

I have 2 questions:

1. Have I calculated the worst-case running time here correctly?
2. how would I prove that Hydrosort(A, 1, n) correctly sorts an array A of n elements?

Comment: You title asks whether the data is sorted correctly. The next-to-last line of the question asks about the worst case running time. What is the question?

Comment: Please edit your question (and its headline). Your headline should point out (brief and precise) what detail your question aims at (and then match that question!), and your sample code should be correct programming syntax (including how to write comments).

Comment: @HelpingHand thank you for the advice!

Comment: @AdrianHHH I have made the corrections. I have 2 questions regarding this pseudocode. One concerns a proof, and the other is a verification of the run time :)

Comment: Operation
`sort A[i…j] by insertion-sort`
is limited by some constant,
the maximal time of sorting an array of 10 elements,
so, it is not O(n^2), you can simply count it as O(1).

Comment: Also, the intervals `[i, m1]` and `[m2, j]`
have not `n/2` elements, but `3n/4`, 
so it should be `T(3n/4)` instead of `T(n/2)`.

Comment: This looks like a variation of [stooge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stooge_sort) and is definitely not O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

> Have I calculated the worst-case running time here correctly?

I am afraid not.
The complexity function is:

```
T(n) = 3T(3n/4) + CONST
```

This is because:

1. You have three recursive calls for a problem of size `3n/4`
2. The constant modifier here is `O(1)`, since all non recursive calls operations are bounded to a constant size (Specifically, insertion sort for n<=10 is `O(1)`).

[If you go on and calculate it](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=T%28n%29+%3D+3T%283n%2F4%29+%2B+1), you'll get worse than `O(n^2)` complexity

> how would I prove that Hydrosort(A, 1, n) correctly sorts an array A
>   of n elements?

By induction. Assume your algorithm works for problems of size `n`, and let's examine a problem of size `n+1`. For `n+1<10` it is trivial, so we ignore this case.

- After first recursive call, you are guaranteed that first 3/4 of the
  array is sorted, and in particular you are guaranteed that the first n/4 of the elements are the smallest ones in this part. This means, they cannot be in the last n/4 of the array, because there are at least n/2 elements bigger than them. This means, the n/4 biggest elements are somewhere between m2 and j.
- After second recursive call, since it is guaranteed to be invoked on the n/4 biggest elements, it will place these elements at the end of the array. This means the part between m1 and j is now sorted properly. This also means, 3n/4 smallest elements are somewhere in between i and m1.
- Third recursive call sorts the 3n/4 elements properly, and the n/4 biggest elements are already in place, so the array is now sorted.